# What to use for Electric Upright Bass Amplification?

Tags: amplifiers, bass-guitar, electric-bass-guitar, double-bass

Lately, I've been fascinated by electric upright basses. It started with seeing one in a store, and now I've been looking at EUB's of all price ranges online.

I realized, though, that I'm entirely unclear on the best way to amplify one.

- Acoustic amplifiers? (do they even make acoustic bass amps?)
- Electric (bass guitar) amplifiers?
- DI into a PA (or whatever - maybe a recording device)?
- Something I haven't listed?

Comment: Are you talking about playing live, or initially just for practicing?

Comment: @topomorto Either playing live or recording (home or studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There are specific amps for double basses and they are one of the best choices.
- Amps for electric basses will do, but the sound quality might vary from amp to amp. Cannot guarantee you'll get the best result out of such an amp.
- There are amps that combine the two aforementioned ones. Like the AER Basic Performer (which I have and I can say for sure it's a good choice for both).
- You can also use some kind of pre amp and connect it directly from that to the console they use at live shows, which is a good choice if you don't have enough money to buy an amp or cannot carry one.

Comment: I appreciate the information, but I'm not sure this applies to electric (solid body) upright/double basses. Models like the Dean Pace Contra or Palatino VE-550 (or more expensive models). Does the DI/preamp bullet apply? I'm assuming the amp models do, but not the mics.

Comment: Just discard the mics option

Answer (score 0):

I am having a good time with my fender 100 bass amp (Rumble), but still looking to embellish it a bit ( I see the larger 200w has a tweeter).
The sound I am told by DB players, sounds quite a lot like an upright.
I use my Ibanez Upswing with rotosound (nylon coated stainless) strings. Previously I had a Stagg, which i used weedwackers on. This current set-up is definitely superior, I feel. Before the 100w Rumble I used the 60w version. The 100w seems so much better.